# function is running before my redux state is available, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that is getting is state from redux. I have a provider that is dispatching an action to get state, then is passing that state down to this component with useContext
This works on every other render which is weird....
refresh, get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
refresh, works fine.
refresh, works fine.
refresh, get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
refresh works, fine.

The problem is when I try to run a find on the state, I get the error

Im guessing the state is not updating fast enough and the computer is trying to forEach over something that doesn't exist?

Here is my code below

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ChatContext } from '../../../context/Context';

const ChatConversation = ({ conversation }) => { // mapped over a "conversations array" is component above this one and pass a conversation ---> looks like [ 'Oxt56Beix' ]
  const { conversationMessages } = useContext(ChatContext);
  const message = conversationMessages.find(({ messagesId }) => messagesId === conversation.messagesId); // this find is throwing error every other render or so
  
 
  return (
    
    <div>
    <h2>{message}</h2>
    </div>
)
 {
```

here is my conversationMessages reducer

```
import { LIST_CONVERSATION_MESSAGES } from '../actions/types';


export default function (state = [ {
    messagesId: 1,
    content: []
  }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      
        case LIST_CONVERSATION_MESSAGES:
          return action.payload
            default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Here is a snapshot of my Provider wrapping this component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import { ChatContext } from '../../context/Context';

const ChatProvider = ({ children }) => {
const conversationMessages = useSelector((state) => state.conversationMessages)

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listConversationMessages())
  }, [])

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listConversations())
  }, [])

const value = {
    conversations,
    conversationMessages,
  };

 
  return <ChatContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ChatContext.Provider>;
};


export default ChatProvider;
```

Comment: It looks like you are mutating the state invariant. Sometimes it's the initial state which is an array, and sometimes it's already been updated by `action.payload` and not an array. Can you update to include full and complete reducer code, and what the `action.payload` value it that you are updating the state to?

Comment: You have an initial state so it could be the opposite problem.  You could be trying to access the state after it's no longer available.  This would happen if you dispatch an action with type `LIST_CONVERSATION_MESSAGES` and payload `undefined` because your reducer replaces the entire state with `action.payload`.

Comment: Do you think my issue is that I am calling the useSelector to get the state and then passing it down from the provider? should I be calling useSelector in each component?

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was in my reducer.

My action.payload was coming back as an OBJECT

Even though In my backend function I was res.json with an array, the action.payload was an OBJECT that CONTAINED the array in a data key

I changed my reducer to

````
import { LIST_CONVERSATION_MESSAGES } from '../actions/types';


export default function (state = [ {
    messagesId: 1,
    content: []
  }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      
        case LIST_CONVERSATION_MESSAGES:
          return action.payload.data // solution was to use action.payload.data instead of action.payload
            default:
            return state;
    }
}```
````